# How do I deploy a node.js three.js webpage that uses Vite?

Tags: node.js, heroku, three.js, vite, heroku-cli

I am using the Heroku CLI and running Heroku Local Web works on the app and hosts it locally on my 3000 port.

However, after pushing the git to Heroku the application fails.
When I check the heroku logs I get the following errors:

```
2023-02-26T05:20:38.239055+00:00 app[web.1]: > three-demo@0.0.0 dev
2023-02-26T05:20:38.239056+00:00 app[web.1]: > vite
2023-02-26T05:20:38.239056+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-02-26T05:20:38.256658+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: vite: not found
2023-02-26T05:20:38.435246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-02-26T05:20:38.483557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-02-26T08:07:23.746257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-02-26T08:07:27.472544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run dev`
2023-02-26T08:07:29.393334+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
2023-02-26T08:07:29.449677+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-02-26T08:07:29.449678+00:00 app[web.1]: > three-demo@0.0.0 dev
2023-02-26T08:07:29.449679+00:00 app[web.1]: > vite
2023-02-26T08:07:29.449679+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-02-26T08:07:29.455486+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: vite: not found
2023-02-26T08:07:29.594499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-02-26T08:07:29.643648+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My intuition was that the problem might be with package.json which looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "three-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.128.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "17.4.0"
  }
}
```

In addition, this is what my project library looks like, would the problem stem from the node_modules library and Heroku being unable to import dependencies from it?

[image: project library screenshot]